# Playing video on the local computer using HTML5 page

Tags: internet-explorer, html5-video

I have a simple HTML page, contains the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Video Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<video id="video" src="1.mp4" autoplay controls></video>

</body>
</html>
```

When trying to open it using IE10 I just get a blank white rectangle with the video controls on it, but no video is shown.

I tried also to set up an IIS server, put the video file in C:\inetpub\wwwroot, changed the video source to:

```
<source src="http://<iis host address>/1.mp4" type="video/mp4"  />
```

but still with no luck.

Any idea, please?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try the page in something other than IE, Firefox, chrome, opera, safari, etc.
If it don't work with those then check that 1.mp4 actually exists...

You also need to check the video carefully

"Internet Explorer 9 supports all profiles of H.264 video and either AAC or MP3 audio in an MP4 container" (From http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html#what-works) ( I know you used 10, but will still need the same codecs)

If you open the video in something like VLC it can tell you what codecs the video uses.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The video is H.264 in MPEG-4 container, Baseline@L3.1, audio is AAC. Firefox 9.0.1 also doesn't show the video.

Comment: I'd do what Abudayah suggests then, try another file. You can download some free videos from somewhere like http://www.bigbuckbunny.org/index.php/download/ These should work 'out of the box' and not require any re encoding

Comment: It is defiantly your video that is the problem...
I have just tried a bunch of mp4s and firefox and chrome(ium) didn't like them. However when I downloaded a ogv they were fine.
Try downloading http://www.jplayer.org/video/ogv/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270.ogv and see if that helps.
There is also http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270_h264aac.m4v 
but I couldn't get that to work. It may need some server side stuff doing

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that appropariate content type header is being set by the server while serving this video. Otherwise it might not get recognized by browser.